# Zonal quaternionic polynomials

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

I've done a R package which computes the Jack polynomials (I started it a couple of years ago). It also computes the zonal polynomials (Jack with $\alpha=2$ up to a normalizing factor), the Schur polynomials (Jack with $\alpha=1$ up to a normalizing factor), and the zonal quaternionic polynomials (Jack with $\alpha=\frac12$ up to a normalizing factor). I don't remember where I saw the zonal quaternionic polynomials, and I'm wondering what are they useful for?

Comment: Does [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3379) help ?